# How to pull data inside "span" for VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need the span value "0.062540" to pull from website through VBA.

{[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55wQw.png)

My code is below:

```
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer    
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    ie.Visible = False    
    ie.navigate "https://www.tefas.gov.tr/FonAnaliz.aspx?FonKod=MAC"
    
    Do 
    DoEvents Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Set doc = ie.document
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    output = doc.getElementsByClassName("top-list").getElementByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    Sheet1.Range("B19").Value = output
    
    ie.Quit   
End Sub
```

However, I could not fetch the related value. Could you help with my problem?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and check which errors you get! This line hides all your error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. If you don't see them you cannot fix them, therefore your code cannot work. Never use this line as you did. Either remove it or implemet a proper error handling according [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove `On Error Resume Next` and check which errors you get! This line hides **all** your error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. If you don't see them you cannot fix them, therefore your code cannot work.

Never use this line as you did. Either remove it or implemet a proper error handling according [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Then if you do all these actions in one line like

```
output = doc.getElementsByClassName("top-list").getElementByTagName("span")(0).innerText
```

the error can be in multiple positions in that line and it is almost impossible to debug it and find out where in that line it is. Therefore we need to split that line up into multiple single actions to see in which part the error **exactly** occurs.

So we split it up like below which is exactly the same as the one line above:

```
Dim Divs As Object  'collection of div elements
Set Divs = doc.getElementsByClassName("top-list")

Dim Spans As Object  'collection of span elements
Set Spans = Divs.getElementByTagName("span")

Dim Output As String
Output = Spans(0).innerText
```

Now we will see that finding the `div` with a class `top-list` works. And we get an error at finding the `Span` elements. So if we have a look at the `Divs` variable we see that it is an collection of **multiple** items. Therefore we need to access the first item in that collection like `Divs(0)`. Furthermore it is not `getElementByTagName` but `getElementsByTagName` (with an `s`). So correcting it to the following:

```
Dim Divs As Object  'collection of div elements
Set Divs = doc.getElementsByClassName("top-list")
Dim Spans As Object  'collection of span elements
Set Spans = Divs(0).getElementsByTagName("span")

Dim Output As String
Output = Spans(0).innerText
```

and we see it works.

---

Finally it is a good idea to implement some error handling, so in case something goes wrong you don't end up with hidden Internet Explorer windows that get never closed:

```
Public Sub FetchNumber()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer 
    
    On Error Goto SAFE_QUIT   'make sure in case of error ie.quit is called.
    ie.Visible = False    
    ie.navigate "https://www.tefas.gov.tr/FonAnaliz.aspx?FonKod=MAC"
    
    Do 
    DoEvents Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    
    Dim Divs As Object
    Set Divs = doc.getElementsByClassName("top-list")
    Dim Spans As Object
    Set Spans = Divs(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
    
    Dim Output As String
    Output = Spans(0).innerText

SAFE_QUIT:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    On Error Goto 0 're activate error reporting
    ie.Quit   
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```